# Improve GPS Accuracy

Tags: geolocation, gps, device, tracking

Hi all I am developing a new mobile app but we are having trouble with the accuracy for one of the features which is a panic button. The problem is we have it set on the highest accuracy (10 meters) using Google Maps Api but it is still off by about 6 meters. If you look at the screenshot, I we are actually at 3806 W. Camino Real and we really don't want people getting the wrong address when the panic button is pressed (shows 3810 W. Camino Real which is wrong). My question is how do we program the app to be more accurate? Or is there an addon anyone could recommend??

Below is screen
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should go outside into the street and press the button.  See whether you are getting a more accurate location report.

Comment: 6 meters accuracy indoor? You won't get anything better than that.